# How can i retrieve only emails from "Focused" tab in outlook using Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the following api endpoint call to get emails from outlook:

First I run

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
```

to get the user id

Then I run

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/mailFolders/Inbox/Messages
```

But Outlook has 2 tabs , "Focused" and "Other"

How can i get the emails in the Focused only ?

Answer (score 1):

Filter messages by `inferenceClassification` property. The possible values are `Focused` and `Other`, which indicate whether the user considers that message as, respectively, more important and less important.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/mailFolders/Inbox/Messages?$filter=inferenceClassification eq 'focused'
```

For the signed-in user you can call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=inferenceClassification eq 'focused'
```

Resource:

[Manage Focused Inbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/manage-focused-inbox?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: doesnt seem to get the messages in Focused only , they are random messages that exist in other inbox subfolders.  I have only 2 emails in focused , i though the response would give back only 2 in Json format. But there are other random emails . not sure why

Comment: also its only getting todays messages not last weeks